# Hyperledger Fabric: Service discovery for private data collection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, private, service-discovery, data-collection, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

In Hyperledger Fabric, does service discovery support finding query peers for private data collection (PDC).

In a channel consisting of 2 orgs (org1 and org2), if I create a PDC for org1 only, only the peers in org1 hold the private data. If in PDC collection profile I specify memberReadOnly=false, it allows org2 users to query org1 peer to read the private data.
But this requires the support of service discovery in peers and Fabric Java SDK.

The objective we'd like to accomplish is in client side as org2 user, via Java SDK, when calling chaincode to read the private data, the SDK will automatically connect to org1 peer.

Is this currently supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, discovery supports private data.

If you take a look at the [discovery CLI](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-cli.html) which implements the client side API (apart from SDKs) you will see that the [endorsement query](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery-cli.html#endorsers-query) has a `--collection` flag.

For example the following flags `--chaincode=cc1 --chaincode=cc2 --collection=cc2:col1` to the `discover endorsers` command mean you want to ask about a transaction which writes to chaincodes `cc1` and `cc2` and also while invoking `cc2` you are writing/reading to/from collection `col`.

In Fabric 2.1 we added another flag `--noPrivateReads` which hints discovery that you only want to write to the collection but not read from it.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the --collection in discover cli. We tried and evaluated the behavior of discover with and without --collection. It looks like without --collection endorsers are found based on chaincode endorsement policy(CCEP), and with --collection endorsers are found based on privated data collection (PDC) endorsement policy(PDCEP). In general cases, the final endorsement policy have to be merged for for CCEP and PDCEP. But I cannot find it implemented in Java SDK. Maybe it's under development. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

Comment: ask in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-java